# error with JSSE on ubuntu 12 while using oauth with facebook via scribe

Tags: java

I was able to successfully use scribe with facebook for authentication.  On a different computer, I am now receiving the following error message:

```
jre/lib/jsse.jar: error reading zip file
```

The exception points to:

```
NoClassDefFoundError occured : javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection
```

Besides reinstalling Java on this box, is there any other thing I can do to further troubleshoot this issue?  JDK version is 1.6.0_35 (I cannot use JDK 7 for this app as of now).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I re-installed JDK 6 on Ubuntu which resolved the problem.  I am not certain what caused the issue with the previous installation.  Hope it helps.